# Does EF SaveChanges insert before update?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am currently getting a constraint error using Entity Framework SaveChanges. I am working on an instance of a class `Parameter` which has an `ICollection<ParameterScore>`.

The entity class looks like this

```
public partial class ParameterScore
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int ParameterId { get; set; }
    public int SortNo { get; set; }
    public string CategoryValue { get; set; }
    public Nullable<double> RangeMin { get; set; }
    public Nullable<double> RangeMax { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> Score { get; set; }

    public virtual Parameter Parameter { get; set; }
}
```

The problem is that initially 3 of these `ParameterScores` has been added and saved to a parameter, say Parameter 1. This works fine.

Now a User adds 2 new `ParameterScores` to the Parameter. As you can see `ParameterScore`has a `SortNo` which is used to sort the intervals. So once a new `ParameterScore`has been added I have to ensure the `SortNo` still guarantees the order in the `ParameterScores`. This is done using a simple algorithm

```
list = list.OrderBy(r => r.RangeMin).ToList();

foreach (var element in list)
{
    element.SortNo = sortNo;
    sortNo++;
}
```

Now I have a single list of all `ParameterScores` with corresponding`SortNo` which I want to persist in my Database. I convert the List to a Collection and assign it to the Parameters `ICollection<ParameterScore>` and call `SaveChanges()`

This results in a constraint error on insertion of duplicate SortNo.

`CONSTRAINT [U_ParameterScore_ParameterId_SortNo] UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED ([ParameterId] ASC, [SortNo] ASC)` 
since I dont want multiple `ParameterScores` being equal.

The way I see it I am reassigning a new Collection to the Parameter which DOES NOT include duplicate SortNo's - which should result in EF inserting all `ParameterScores`and overwriting the existing ones.

Does EF insert the new Collection before deleting the old one? Or am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: I don't know about your direct question, but this should work if you first delete the existing `ParameterScores`.

Comment: I think its not just about inserts... afaik, EF will update your entities one by one and then commit all... so if you increase `SortNo` by 1 for multiple entities, you risk an intermediate state, where the update of one entity interfers with the pending update of another.

Comment: @grek40 I think you are correct. This is probably what happens - and as @Dan Dumitru suggests deleting `ParameterScores` might work, I am just looking for 1) confirmation about how EF behaves 2) a possible cleaner/easier solution than having to delete some records which I am about to overwrite